# Trigger after updating the document at couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am using the couchDB and I just wanted to fire a http request when any updation is performed at the couchDb side.I am updating the document using the java api (in an android application).Thanks in advance any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB does not send requests (it only responds to them).

However, you could implement a worker script (e.g. in node JS), which connects to CouchDB's [changes feed](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html#long-polling) with the `feed=longpolling` option. 
Then you can keep listening to changes as they happen and react to them in any way necessary - for instance, send an HTTP request.

If you're thinking about implementing this in node, the [follow](https://github.com/iriscouch/follow) npm package might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to implement that with PouchDB `live sync`, like below:

```
var localDB = new PouchDB('localdb')
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://192.168.1.106:5984/remotedb')

localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
    // Something changed
    // trigger appropriate events here
})
```